# Sql Server BI Development Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

Do i need to install vs 2008 professional before full installation of sql server 2008 developer edition with BI Development Studio ?

On MS page we can find that ...

"Business Intelligence Development Studio is **Microsoft Visual Studio 2008** with additional project types that are specific to SQL Server business intelligence. Business Intelligence Development Studio is the primary environment that you will use to develop business solutions that include Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects. Each project type supplies templates for creating the objects required for business intelligence solutions, and provides a variety of designers, tools, and wizards to work with the objects"

**which version of vs 2008** ? professional ? express ? standard ??

thnx in advance :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't.

If you don't have VS installed, the BI Dev Studio installation will install a VS shell called Visual Studio Premier Partner Edition. Look in Add or Remove Programs for an entry like this.

BIDS is related to SQL Server licencing, not VS and it is only provided with the Standard, Enterprise and Developer Editions.

Answer (score 1):

No, If you are going to create BI projects only, then you dont need to install Visual Studio at all

When you install Sql Server, just make sure to select the Business Develpoment Studio option, then the installer will install the Studio IDE with the templates needed for creating BI projects